# Have WYGWAM image insert be able to select from multiple directories

Tags: wygwam, file-manager

I am currently using WYGWAM 3.3.3 with EE 2.11.1.  I have WYGWAM using EE's file manager.  Currently with file manager there are 6 different folders they can upload images and pdf's to.  When they create an article (entry) and in the body content I have a WYGWAM field I want to give them the option to select an image from any of their 6 upload folders.  I know when I setup I can only select one and when you click browse folder it will bring up that folder.

This makes sense as if they upload a new file it knows where to put it but is there any way to allow them to look in the other folders for existing assets to insert?

Comment: what happens if you don't specify a folder? EE will normally give you the options for the folders you have rights to upload into

Comment: Works like a charm.  Sometimes it is the obvious things.  Thanks and feel free to leave as an answer and I will make it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens if you don't specify a folder? EE will normally give you the options for the folders you have rights to upload into